# input text validation within modal dialog prompt out if not meet the min max range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

Its possible to so something like, Let say i have a few of input text use validation. For example this input min is 5 and max is 10. If value is still within this min max it wont appear modal dialog, else if the value insert in the input is lower then 5 or more than 10 dialog yes/no will prompt, if click YES two hidden input text will appear under the first input text, if click NO it will appear one input text under the first input text. How to perform this? There will be a lot of validation input and all of it will go through this process same.

Comment: Please visit help center, take tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: this kind of validation even is less than min and more than max still able to submit the form

Comment: You might want to share your current code and what are the things you have tried already.

Comment: @GurupadHegde currently code im using bootstrapValidator.. As additional im wanted to have something that i mention above. You might familiar with bootstrapValidator. Currently im only have such code. I just wanted to enhance it to have such way.

Comment: @parkway you need to provide a code which is reproducible by others. Also, add expected Behavior in cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

I found another alternative already. By removing the bootstrapvalidator and use jquery to validate manually